# Is the inverse relation from $R =_{def} \{ (x,y) | x^2 -1 =y \} \subseteq \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{R} $ a function?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The inverse from $R =_{def} \{ (x,y) | x^2 -1 =y  \} \subseteq \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{R} $ is $R^{-1}:  y \mapsto (y+1)^{\frac{1}{2}} $ but is this a left-total function?

Comment: The term "left-total" is totally nonstandard. Do you mean, Is the domain of the inverse equal to $\Bbb R$? No. How could it be? The domain of the inverse is the range the function $x\mapsto x^2-1\colon \Bbb N\to \Bbb R$, and that isn't (can't be) all of $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

You are incorrect about what $R^{-1}$ is. Rather, for any binary relation $R,$ we have $$R^{-1}:=\bigl\{(u,v):(v,u)\in R\bigl\}.$$ In your particular case, then, $$R^{-1}=\bigl\{(u,v)\in\Bbb R\times\Bbb N:v^2-1=u\bigl\}.$$

In order for this to be a function, we must have that if $(u,v_1),(u,v_2)\in R^{-1}$, then $v_1=v_2.$ Is this true?

As a side note, regardless of whether or not $R^{-1}$ is a function, its domain is *not* $\Bbb R.$

Comment: I upvoted yours and deleted mine (in its initial status it carried a mistake). This to avoid confusion by the OP.

Comment: How very gracious and perspicacious! My thanks (and, shortly, browsing-induced upvotes)!

Comment: Thank you. The words "gracious" and "perspicacious" (I just found out what that means) make me blush. It seems that I found a new strategy for gaining reputation. However, I have forbidden myself to take structural advantage of that strategy :-).